# Set Dynamic SerializedName annotation in android java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Please Fix this I m new to android.

I need to be able to edit the value in the @SerializedName annotation with each call. Here's the JSON response:

```
{
    "rates": {
        "INR": {  //Problem with INR
            "currency_name": "Indian rupee",
            "rate": "74.4600",
            "rate_for_amount": "74.4600"
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my data class:

```
public class Rates {
        @SerializedName("INR") //Set dynamic serializedName annotation here
        private INR INR;
        public CurrencyConverterResponse.INR getINR() {
            return INR;
        }
    }
    public class INR {
        @SerializedName("currency_name")
        private String currencyName;
        @SerializedName("rate")
        private String rate;
        @SerializedName("rate_for_amount")
        private String rateForAmount;

        public String getCurrencyName() {
            return currencyName;
        }
        public String getRate() {
            return rate;
        }
        public String getRateForAmount() {
            return rateForAmount;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks like `Rates` should hold a `Map<String, Rate>`, where `Rate` is what you have named the `INR` class in your code snippet.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you make an example with my code, I can't understand sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have limited currencies, So you use like this in Response class

```
public class Rates {

    @SerializedName(value = "INR", alternate = {"USD", "GBP", "EUR", "CHF"})
    private Rate rate;

    public Rate getRate() {
        return rate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For an unlimited number of options, you should use `Map` so it will return currency name and rate, this solution will work also if you want to receive more than one rate

```java
public class Rates {

    private Map<String, Rate> rates;

    public Map<String, Rate> getRates() {
        return rate;
    }
}
```